# On chrome extension v3 how to know if there is at least one runtime listener on

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a very simple chrome extension v3, but most of the content I see out there [includig stackoverflow] no longer works because it was directd to v2.

there is two problems that i need to address:

on my backgroud script if i call `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and the popup is not active, the javascript throws an error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

so it comes question 1

is there a way to check if there are any current listeners for `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` on manifest v3???

question 2

how can i, from the background script, start the popup? or display any visual message to the user;??

Comment: 1) No, but you can add `.catch(err => ...)` and check err.message. 2) In the future there will be chrome.action.openPopup but it'll have several limitations, so a better method would be to use a notification or open a new window via chrome.windows.create. You can also use `alert()` inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).